# While loops braces {} error in code

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have code which should work, but the braces at the bottom give me an error. There is probably a simple solution that I can't find, probably because I am exhausted. Both of these codes are in different classes. If I erase a brace then another brace gives me an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int f = 0;
        int grade = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter grade scores: ");
        do {
            System.out.print("Grade: ");
            grade = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (grade >= 0 && grade < 60) {
                f++;
            } else if (grade < 70) {
                d++;
            } else if (grade < 80) {
                c++;
            } else if (grade < 90) {
                b++;
            } else if (grade <= 100) {
                a++;
            }

            while (grade >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Total scores: " + (a + b + c + d + f));
                System.out.println("A: " + a);
                System.out.println("B: " + b);
                System.out.println("C: " + c);
                System.out.println("D: " + d);
                System.out.println("F: " + f);
            }
        } // this one gives error
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up do-while loops as you're doing them wrong.

Comment: The structure should be `do { ... } while (...);`. You're missing the `while (...);` part.

Comment: Also unrelated and totally irrelevant but; try to maintain some kind of indent structure of your code. It becomes so much easier to read. For you, and for anyone who is ever going to read your code.

Comment: I formatted your code, but boy am I confused by what you mean "different codes" - they look like they're from the same method/same `main` method.  Since editing that portion out would be destructive and change the meaning of the question, I've got no choice but to ask what you could possibly mean by that.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is

```
do {
} while ( boolean expression) ;
```

You're missing the `while` part

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: what do you mean? isn't this while (next >= 0); a while statement?

Comment: @colors Your `while` is completely independent of the `do` because it appears inside of the curly braces - what you have is a `while` statement inside of a broken `do-while` statement.  You need to have a `while` after (outside of) the curly braces to complete the `do-while` statement

Answer (score 4):

If you read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) this is what a `do while` loop should look like:

```
do {
  statement(s)
} while (expression);
```

What you currently have is:

```
do { 

}
```

and so you are missing the `while (expression) ;` portion.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the 'while' part in your code. A do-while loop has to have a condition to check against after each iteration. Your syntax should look something like:

```
do
{
//code here
}
while (condition-here);
```

Note: do-while loops take a semi-colon at the end of the statement. Don't miss that

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int grade = 0;
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter grade scores: ");
    do{
        System.out.print("Grade: ");
        grade = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(grade >= 0 && grade < 60){
            f++;
        }
        else if(grade < 70){
            d++;
        }
        else if(grade < 80){
            c++;
        }
        else if(grade < 90){
            b++;
        }
        else if(grade <= 100){
            a++;
        } 

    } while (grade >= 0)

        System.out.println("Total scores: " + (a + b + c + d + f));
        System.out.println("A: " + a);
        System.out.println("B: " + b);
        System.out.println("C: " + c);
        System.out.println("D: " + d);
        System.out.println("F: " + f);

}
```